# the address of GImage

Tags: java, graphics

So I want to set address of image, but there is some problem, I know that there is another way: add this image to this project folder and just write the name, but How can I do that way?(with full address).

```
GImage Image = new GImage("D:\Users\Oservice\Desktop\gravity.jpg");
```

Comment: This is my problem: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java a single backslash is a escape sequence. The next character after the slash will have a different meaning. For instance:

- `"\""` (a string containing a quote character).
- `"\u0061"` (a string with the uppercase letter A).
- `"\r\n"` (a pair of CR LF control characters).

If you want to specify a backlash as part of your string, you will need to prefix it by another backslash: `D:\\Users\\Oservice\\Desktop\\gravity.jpg`, or replace them with forward slashes (`D:/Users/Oservice/Desktop/gravity.jpg`).

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GImage.html#GImage%28String%29), it works like this:

1. Check to see if an image with that name has already been defined. If so, return that image.
2. Check to see if there is a resource available with that name whose contents can be read as an Image. If so, read the image from the resource file.
3. Load the image from a file with the specified name, relative to the application directory or the applet code base.

If it's complaining about escape characters try using `\\` instead of `\` in the image path.

Comment: This is my problem: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ ) –

Comment: Updated to respond to your comment